# separate(give margins) textviews in linear layout

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a layout with a `TextView` inside a `Linearlayout` which is inflating on selecting a item from a spinner.

The result is like this:

[image]

What I want it to be is like this:

[image]

This is my `tag_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tag_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="6dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chip_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="#Tag2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Linear Layout in which this view will be inflated:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tag_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tag_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/issuesStrengthsBrandspinner"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" />
```

This is my background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

and this is how I'm infalting the view:

```
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.tag_container);

        for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry : issuesStrengthsbrandNameIDMap.entrySet()){
            View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tag_layout, null);
            Log.i("NAME", "onItemClick: "+entry.getValue());
            ((TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.chip_text)).setText(entry.getValue());
            linearLayout.addView(view2);
        }
```

Comment: replace padding with margin in the tag_view layout

Answer (score 1):

Try this set Margin Programatically

```
for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry : issuesStrengthsbrandNameIDMap.entrySet()){
     View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tag_layout, null);
     Log.i("NAME", "onItemClick: "+entry.getValue());
     TextView tv=  (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.chip_text)).setText(entry.getValue();
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     params.setMargins(10,0,10,0); //setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
     tv.setLayoutParams(params);
     linearLayout.addView(tv);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give margin to your `TextView`

```
android:marginLeft="8dp"
android:marginRight="8dp"
```

Eg.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chip_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:marginLeft="8dp"
    android:marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="#Tag2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: Try giving more margin eg. 24dp

Comment: You are giving code of `tag_view.xml:` but inflating `R.layout.tag_layout` Make sure you are using correct file.

Comment: oh sorry about that it should be tag_layout.xml instead of tag_view.xml. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove background attribute from root linear layout and add in text-view. this will create separate text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="6dp"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingTop="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chip_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="#Tag2"
        android:background="@drawable/tag_background"
        android:marginLeft="8dp"
        android:marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Happy coding!!